# Resize c3.js chart after removing "display:none" form div

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have a function to pre load element and use **"display:none"** to hidden an chart

```
<div class="col-sm-9 topTenWebCus" ></div>
```

javscript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $(".topTenWebCus").css("display","none");
        },200);
});
```

And afterward i got another onclick function to remove the **"display:none"** css

```
$("#buttonFire").click(function(){
                        $(".topTenWeb30d").css("display","none");
                        $(".topTenWebCus").css("display","block");  
                    });
```

It works fine. but it wouldn't re-size itself even i have insert bootstrap into the website.

I am thinking about to use inner function to do .resize() but it's not working, is there better way to fix the resize issue?

[image]

**Update 1:**

The chart would resize itself if user change zoom rate.

I just figure out one important thing, the chart display correctly if the zoom rate is 100%, but if the user change the zoom rate the chart will not resize to a appropriate size.

**Update2**
I try to use .show() and .hide() but no luck

**Sample solution**

```
$("#buttonFire").click(function(){
                        $(".topTenWeb30d").css("display","none");
                        $(".topTenWebCus").css("display","block");  
                          chart.flush() // chart depends on your chart's name it could be anything like charrt112.flush()
                    });
```

Comment: sorry i made a mistake

Comment: how about using jquery `hide()` and `show()`?

Comment: Is the size correct *before* you hide the element with display:none?

Comment: Try to draw it when the div is shown instead of to draw it when div is hidden. Simple way is to redraw it after button click.

Comment: which charting library are you using?

Comment: the chart's should be correct

Comment: pls, check the update to my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem doesn't seem to be with boorstrap. Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18647/), your exact code works fine for showing the correct column width after displaying back.

Without more information on what charting library you are using, my guess is like most charting libraries your's gets its size when it is first rendered. When the div size changes, you will have to manually call things like `resize` , `redraw` or `referesh` etc on your chart object depending on your chart library.

If you can point out your chart library, or even better update my jsFiddle example to show your chart, it will be easier to figure out how you can make the chart refit.

**Update for c3.js**

After you re-display your div try calling `chart.flush();` and see if it resizes correctly.

```
$("#buttonFire").click(function(){
    $(".topTenWeb30d").css("display","none");
    $(".topTenWebCus").css("display","block");
    chart.flush(); // use reference to your chart object
});
```

If the `chart.flush()` does not work, as a last option you can set the width, height of the chart dynamically based on your div dimensions like so.

```
chart.resize({
  height: $(".topTenWebCus").innerHeight(),
  width: $(".topTenWebCus").innerWidth()
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it's doesn't looks like it would flush. As long as i declare my chart as chart8 i even do chart8.flush() but no luck.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here, you may have to post your chart code in your question. It will help if you can update the jsFiddle with your chart code. Also, try the `resize` option I just updated in my answer. Or are you getting error on console that you cannot access chart object?

Comment: Sorry tried again, the flush method is actually working! i should update my answer for the community

Comment: glad it worked! You don't need to update answers in your question. That actually works against stackoverflow convention. A accepted answer is enough to tell people what worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you require this if I am understanding you correctly:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   $("#buttonFire").trigger('click');
});
```